# GetStorage doesn't save list edits flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i'm facing an issue whith **GetStorage**.

i'm using **GetStorage** to store locally my list data and I'm able to save and load my list data but when i modify an element of my list, that modification isn't saved. I don't know why but GetStorage is able to save the data when i'm adding a new element to the list by writing `list.add(data)` or when i remove an element from the list with `list.removeAt(index)`.

**But when i modify a value and hot reload the app, the modified value isn't loaded but the initial value is loaded.** For example, when i edit a String `getxController.list[index].name = 'New Name'` the new Name won't be saved.

Here is my add function in getX controller:

```
var tile = <TileClass>[].obs;

void addTile({int tileNumber, String tileName, String tag}) {
    TileClass data = TileClass(
      number: tileNumber,
      tileName: tileName,
      resetValue: 0,
      tag: tag,
      add: 1,
      substract: 1,
      color: blue.value,
    );
    tile.add(data);
    update();
  }
```

I init **GetStorage** in the main funtion `await GetStorage.init();` and here is the init function in getx controller to load saved data :

```
final storage = GetStorage();
@override
void onInit() {
  List data = storage.read<List>('tileData');
  if (data != null) {
    tile = data.map((e) => TileClass.fromJson(e)).toList().obs;
  }
  ever(counter, (_) {
    storage.write('tileData', tile.toList());
  });
  super.onInit();
}
```

Here is my ListView.builder :

```
class TileList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final controller = Get.find<Appcontroller>();
    
    return GetBuilder<Appcontroller>(
      init: Get.find(),
      builder: (_) {
        return Obx(
          () => ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: controller.counter.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {

              var tileIndex = controller.counter[index];

              return ContainerModel( // this is a template which contain tile class elements
                number: tileIndex.number,
                name: tileIndex.counterName,
                iindex: index,
                color: tileIndex.color,
                tag: tileIndex.tag,
                onSubstract: () {
// This function help me to edit the number of a tile. It's this edit which is not saved
                  tileIndex.number = tileIndex.number - tileIndex.substract;
                  controller.update();
                },
                onAdd: () {
//This function also help me to edit the number of a tile. and the edit which is not saved.
                  controller.addAudio();
                  tileIndex.number += tileIndex.add;
                  controller.update();
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Please could someone help me to solve this issue ?